# Frequent SSL Certificate Detachment Issue with Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Load Balancer

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, load-balancing, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am relatively new to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI), and I am encountering an issue with the configuration of my load balancer. Specifically, I have set up two listeners and two backend sets in my load balancer to handle traffic on ports 80 and 443.

One of these listeners is responsible for redirecting traffic arriving on port 80 via ingress, while the other is configured for port 443 to handle secure HTTPS traffic. I have attached an SSL certificate to the listener associated with port 443. In the initial configuration,

- The "Use SSL" option is selected
- The certificate resource is set to "Load Balancer Managed Certificate"
- The backend set is configured to use the listener associated with port 80 (which does not use SSL).

However, I have been encountering an issue where the SSL configuration intermittently reverts to the following settings:

- "Use SSL" is not selected
- Certificate resource is changed to "Certificate Service Managed Service"
- The backend set is switched to use the listener associated with port 443 (the one that uses SSL).

I am seeking insights into why this issue occurs periodically and guidance on resolving it. Any assistance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.